# Locally downloading arifacts from Maven for Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, artifactory

I'm currently investigating ways to use Gradle and Artifactory efficiently for my company. I was able to build a few small test programs depending on each other and junit for testing.
One of the things we want to achieve is to have the third party libraries we use on our local Server with Artifactory (so not a mirror from Maven). And this is where some problems came up: junit could not function without hamcrest.
So my question is:

> Is there a simple way to download an artefact from Maven along with it's dependencies in one go to avoid waste of time and frustration at build time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: You don't need to. Artifactory has the notion of remote repositories, which proxy repositories like maven central and jcenter, providing you with transparent dependencies (and transitive dependencies) resolution.

Here is [a simple example](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/gradle-example-minimal) of a project which has Gradle build that works with Artifactory (using Artifactory Gradle plugin). Feel free to copy-paste.

Comment: Yes I know that but as I mentioned one of the requirements is to have everything locally, so no Mirror/Proxy.

Comment: When you proxy something, it is stored locally. Or did you mean you don't have Internet connection at all? If so, it's not very clear from the question.

Comment: The point about not using a proxy is that you have exact control on your dependencies, what you use and which version you use. Meaning all the developers work with the same version of junit for example. Another example is that if you use the lastest version of a library from your local repository, you'll use the one that everyone uses in the company but the same command might give you a different download (when using a proxy) to say John who started using this library a month ago.

Comment: I wanted to find out if there was a gradle way to solve that, an additional command of some sort.   
Proxy is actually half of the solution I found: I run a gradle script that has a list of my dependencies with the command "gradle dependencies" and using jcenter. It downloads everything in jcenter-cache and I copy it from there to my 'closed-off' local repository.

Comment: Got it. Yes, Proxy is half. Other will be issuing a REST call to move (promote) the artifacts you want to your "clean" local repository. You can execute this REST command from Gradle.